# Records for DNS when setting server side TAG Manager with Cloudflare

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-tag-manager

I´m setting CAPI with the TAG Manager side. I´m not sure what settings to use for the subdomain using the DNS records provided by Google Cloud Platform in Cloudflare. I have all set up, but not sure about this part.

I use Cloudflare, the A and AAAA records should use the @ for the main domain or the subdomian.maindomain.com as an alias? For example
type A

name subdomian.maindomain.com
Content 216.458.25.15
or
type A
name maindomain.com
Content 216.458.25.15
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The nake domain @ must be an A record. The rest of your question is too confusing to create an answer.

Comment: I just find the answer, if anyone wonder is
type A
name subdomian.maindomain.com
Content 216.458.25.15

Answer (score 0):

Im really struggling with this too. The google app engine doesnt seem to register the certificate.

This is what my DNS entries look like. Is it normal for the google app engine to take MORe than 2 hours to register the cert?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CC21.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).